# OAuthNotAuthorizedException, When twitter is run in android application

Tags: android, twitter, twitter-oauth, android-twitter

I am working on an application in which I had to make a new project from existing code. The parent project contains Twitter support classes and Twitter is working fine in that application. But in the newly created project, the Twitter throws following error:

```
oauth.signpost.exception.OAuthNotAuthorizedException: Authorization failed (server replied
with a 401). This can happen if the consumer key was not correct or the signatures did not
match.
```

This is quite strange for me. Twitter does not work. However if i run the old snippet it works...Why not on the new one? when there is no difference between the Twitter implementation in the both projects. I have verified date/time on the devices..but that is not issue. Any help please..???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With what you have posted it is nearly impossible to help you. i can just provide some help:

First check the keys (secret and id) you got from twitter.

Check your permissions (probably have this right since it is a response from twitter)

Then check if your Auth process is going ok. that is if the Request is signed right,

then check the auth callback, if it was processed correctly (how does your implementation return the oauth token?).

Comment: @ DArkO ... Well the issue was with the callback...Thanks for mentioning all the needed steps to verify Twitter Authentication....